# Android Studio Build failed - attempting to stop daemon

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm having the following error whenever I try to build my application. I have checked that the image has the correct name and is a .png file. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

`AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.2-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\troubleshoot\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3fcc06d4568adad9f26d921b3ce0773c\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon`

Comment: Any luck on this message?

Comment: Yes...I went to Project Structure (Ctrl, Shift, Alt, S) -> Project...then set Android Gradle Plugin Version to 4.0.0 and Gradle Version to 6.5